# Why will or will not the bitcoin infrastructure become unsustainable?

Tags: client, scalability

I am new to bitcoins, but as I understand the technology:

1. All transactions must be downloaded to the client machine (say, Grandma's Windows XP machine from 2003)
2. New transactions are also sent to all clients

Is that correct?

If 1 billion people adopted Bitcoin as their primary currency, and performed an average of 1 transaction per day each, this would be *11,000 transactions per second every day* on Grandma's Windows XP machine.  I think it would catch fire!

Comment: As long as the block size limit doesn't get lifted, you simply can't send that many transactions. => Transaction cost will rise, and most transactions will be off-chain.

Comment: This has been discussed many, many times. To find some of those discussions, google "bitcoin scalability" and "bitcoin SPV"

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is going to happen when it is totally infeasible to download the entire bitcoin transaction history?](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/what-is-going-to-happen-when-it-is-totally-infeasible-to-download-the-entire-bit)

Answer (score 2):

I will let Satoshi Nakamoto answer this:

> Long before the network gets anywhere near as large as that, it would
>   be safe  for users to use Simplified Payment Verification (section 8)
>   to check for  double spending, which only requires having the chain of
>   block headers, or  about 12KB per day.  Only people trying to create
>   new coins would need to run  network nodes.  At first, most users
>   would run network nodes, but as the  network grows beyond a certain
>   point, it would be left more and more to  specialists with server
>   farms of specialized hardware.  A server farm would  only need to have
>   one node on the network and the rest of the LAN connects with  that
>   one node.
>
> The bandwidth might not be as prohibitive as you think.  A typical
>   transaction  would be about 400 bytes (ECC is nicely compact).  Each
>   transaction has to be  broadcast twice, so lets say 1KB per
>   transaction.  Visa processed 37 billion  transactions in FY2008, or an
>   average of 100 million transactions per day.   That many transactions
>   would take 100GB of bandwidth, or the size of 12 DVD or  2 HD quality
>   movies, or about $18 worth of bandwidth at current prices.
>
> If the network were to get that big, it would take several years, and
>   by then,  sending 2 HD movies over the Internet would probably not
>   seem like a big deal.
>
> Satoshi Nakamoto

Link: http://www.mail-archive.com/cryptography@metzdowd.com/msg09964.html